# What's a clean way of installing a newer version of latex on Ubuntu via packages?

Tags: installing, ubuntu

Newer than the repo version that is (2015).

Comment: There isn't. Install TeX Live without using the repo packages. See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092).

Comment: The repo version is `2015`, NOT 2012.

Comment: @AlanMunn Technically, that is surely false. It is always possible to create packages yourself and install those. I don't know why anybody would wish to do so for purely personal use, though, as there is no benefit to be gained and many disadvantages.

Comment: @cfr This depends on your interpretation 'clean'. I take it to mean something like simple and relatively non-error-prone.

Comment: @AlanMunn I interpret it in the Arch Linux sense. Well, actually, I think it is more KISS to use upstream's installer for TL than packaging at all, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @AlanMunn That is, 'simple' means technically so, as opposed to end-user-friendly.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the TeX Live distribution in the official Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 16.04 are still from 2015 as you can see from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/texlive). I would recommend using the [TeX Live 2016 PPA maintained by J Fernyhough](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2016) for updating Tex Live to 2016 and for keeping your TeX Live 2016 packages fairly up-to-date. You can do so by running:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2016
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

> EDIT: 2022-01

Currently you can install an even more actual version of TeX Live (i.e., 2019) for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) and 18.04 (Bionic) at the [TeX Live PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive?field.series_filter=xenial) by the same author. Just run following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive
sudo apt update
```